# How to add condition based selected status in select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang, ruby-on-rails-5

Select field:

```
select#language_top onChange="window.location.href=this.value"
  option value=("#{url_for(locale: 'en')}") data-image=("#{image_url('english.png')}") English
  option value=("#{url_for(locale: 'de')}") data-image=("#{image_url('german.png')}") selected='' German
```

I want to add `selected=''` based on a condition. I have done it like this:

```
select#language_top onChange="window.location.href=this.value"
  - if params[:locale] == "en"
    option value=("#{url_for(locale: 'en')}") data-image=("#{image_url('english.png')}") selected='' English
  - else
    option value=("#{url_for(locale: 'en')}") data-image=("#{image_url('english.png')}") English
  - if params[:locale] == "de"
    option value=("#{url_for(locale: 'de')}") data-image=("#{image_url('german.png')}") selected='' German
  - else
    option value=("#{url_for(locale: 'de')}") data-image=("#{image_url('german.png')}") German
```

I think it can be refactored. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
select#language_top onChange="window.location.href=this.value"
  option selected=(params[:locale] == "en") value=("#{url_for(locale: 'en')}") data-image=("#{image_url('english.png')}") English
  option selected=(params[:locale] == "de") value=("#{url_for(locale: 'de')}") data-image=("#{image_url('german.png')}") German
```